# Error notifications for mobile comments are not working

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

It appears that the error notifications about comments in Mobile Stack Exchange do not work (in-browser mobile site), on many stacks. Something should be done, do we report bugs here?

My original problem was that I've tried to post comments on answers for various boards, and the button wouldn't do anything, no error message or anything. I recently found out that it's because I don't have enough reputation points, but there was no note explaining the rule like in the desktop version. A couple boards I tried it on are the User Experience one and StackOverflow.

Also, user *Mooseman is eating pizza* claims the same about "your message is not long enough" error.

Comment: Was it on your own questions and answers to them? You need a reputation of 50 to comment anywhere although there probably should be a message if that's the case.

Comment: Nope. That must be it... Should I change the question to "why is there no message" then, considering thats the problem now?

Comment: Check the browser console for client side errors. Clicking the "add comment" without enough reputation should open a popover dialog.

Comment: There are no comment error dialogs on mobile. If I type too few characters, the comment fails without notification.

Comment: I don't think there's such thing as browser console in Firefox Android. Someone correct me if I'm wrong, or maybe even check the console on a desktop browser with mobile client. I'd do it but my laptop's outta commission.

Comment: Just to clarify this further I've tried under FF for Android without being logged in, under the default mobile view I see an "add a comment" button but it doesn't do anything. If I request the desktop version I get the usual required rep of 50 / login message. However what Mooseman said is also true and if I try to a comment of "A" while logged in a don't get a notification back, but requesting the full version get the "characters to go" feedback.